# Missing "Users" section in Edgewall Trac0.12.3

Tags: python, linux, trac

I installed Edgewall Trac0.12.3 and added myself to the administrators group. In the administration panel I see the following:

[image]

AFAICR "Users" group must be available here. By using this group, I could add a user, manage his rights, specify mail and so on.

Maybe I need to install some plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a base installation without any plugins, you can only manage user permissions from the web interface (**Permissions** option on your screenshot).

To manage users from the web interface you'll need a 3rd party plug-in like, for example, the [Account Manager Plugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) (there others, so I suggest you first do a survey of which one suits your needs best at [Track Hacks](https://trac-hacks.org/)).

Comment: Actually not so many, I think the only alternative 'Users' admin panel provider is UserManagerPlugin, but even that is rather an extension to AccountManagerPlugin than a substitute. But you'll probably like to only use Users from one, not both at the same time.